# Custom AuthorizeAttribute being called too many times

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I am currently developing some security to protect web service calls. I decided to extend the authorize attribute and overide the isAuthorized function as well as the ActionFilterAttribute OnActionExecuted. However, as i was debugging the program, i noticed that if i was to add [Authorize(Roles = "Read")] class level and [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] on a api function within that class, The isAuthorized is being called 3 times in total. This might not be too big of an issue but since in my isAuthorized, i am creating and validating tokens in a database. It would be ideal if i am able to eliminate this redundant process and work with just isAuthorized being called once per service call.

```
  public class CustomuAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        bool allowedAccess = true;
        ... logic

    }
   }
```

Overriding the OnAction Executed. This actually only gets hits once eventhough the isAuthorized gets hit 3 times.

```
    public class CustomAuthorizeFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
     .. logic
    }
}
```

**Edit**
I have found that adding [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method| AttributeTargets.Class)] onto the authorizeattribute calss solves the issue of being called multiple times

Comment: Could you override onauthorization method and set a breakpoint on it to see how many times it get hit?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply but i overrode the onAutorization and it turns out it also gets get 3 times. OnAuthorization gets hit first, goes to IsAuthorization and returns OnAuthorization.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't add this filter as a global filter? I mean you only have it a controller and action level

Comment: I dont believe i did no

Comment: but youre right. If i take the filters for the controller and action level out, isAuthorization still gets hits once. which is not something i want

Comment: So somewhere your filter registered, global filter, base controller, somewhere. That's the only way mvc can know about your filter